Al publicar en GitPages me muestra el readme
Estoy tratando de subir mi primer proyecto react a GitPages para poder publicarlo y compartirlo. No se porque en vez de mostrarme el index.html GitPages me muestra en el navegador el archivo README



No hay un index.html en tu carpeta raíz, en su lugar muestra el README.md

Rene, eh intentado con commits poner el index.html en la raíz, e incluso borre el README.md pero la pagina me tiraba un 404. Probé varias formas pero no consigo el resultado esperado...

Para GitHub Pages el repositorio debe cumplir varios requisitos y según
observe tu repo no los cumple.
Te dejo los paso completos que debes seguir:
https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages?tab=readme-ov-file

Es mejor si pones los requisitos en la respuesta y dejas el link para referencia solamente.

xllauca gracias por el aporte, he seguido los pasos de la documentación que me enviaste y ahora lo que sucede es que GitPages simplemente me despliega una pagina en blanco. Que podrá ser?
